# How to get changes between two branches and the commit ID that makes the changes

Tags: git, github, branch, git-branch

I got two branches(e.g. test and master). I have made some commits to each of the branches and now I want to see new commits that in test branch but not in master branch.

Currently I am using `git log master..test` to see the commits that in test but not in master. It works well for most of the time, however, it brings a problem. If I have cherry-picked some commits from test branch to master branch, due to the difference in their commit ID, `git log` will still show the commit which have been cherry-picked even if there is actually no difference between two branches.

I am now considering about using `git diff master..test`, this method will compare the content of two branches and give me "accurate" changes (it won't show commit that have been cherry-picked). However, this fails to give me the commit ID I want.

So I am wondering is there any method, maybe some tags, that can show the actual differences between two branches, and at the same time show which commit makes these differences?

UPDATE: Since I am using a program to achieve this, I cannot first look at the difference and then go to `git blame` to match the content and see which commit is responsible. To do that, I will need to use something like grep and that may match the content multiple times if the text content showed up multiple times. So I am looking for some direct link from diff to commit ID

Comment: Look at `git cherry`.  To understand how `git cherry` actually works, look at the symmetric difference section of [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) and then look at the `--cherry-*` options of `git log`. Note also that `git diff` only (well, ignore "combined diffs" which are not what you want anyway) compares *two particular* commits: `git diff A..B` does not look at commits in `git log --ancestry-path --boundary A..B`, it looks only at `A`, then only at `B`.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the **triple-dot notation** of `git diff`, i.e. `git diff [--options] <commit>...<commit>`

Quotation from manpage:

> `git diff [--options] <commit>...<commit> [--] [<path>...]`
>
> This form is to view the changes on the branch containing and up to the second , starting at a common ancestor of both . "git diff A...B" is equivalent to "git diff $(git-merge-base A B) B". You can omit
>              any one of , which has the same effect as using HEAD instead.

Comment: well this method could give me the diff between two branches, but it fails to give me which commit makes these differences, or should I add any option to make it work?

Comment: @JekyllSONG, `<commit1>...<commit2>` is different with `<commit1>..<commit2>`,  it do NOT give the diff between two branch, but list up changes that occurred on the commit2 branch since when the commit1 branch was started off it.

Comment: thank you, I understand this part. But then the next question is, is there any way that I can see for this change, which commit makes this change? For example, I delete a line and commit, then a commit ID is generated, when I use `git diff`, I will be able to see this line in red, but may I know that which commit delete this line?

Comment: @JekyllSONG, `git blame` will show what revision and author last modified each line of a file.

Comment: OK, to be more specific, I am achieving this using program, e.g. `gitpython`. I assume that by using `git blame`, I will look at the text content and match with the content in git blame, but if I use program to achieve this, there might be multiple match so I think there is still a problem.

Comment: @JekyllSONG  `git log -p <commit1>...<commit2>` will show log with patch, Maybe It will more convenient for you to processing.